# How to obtain Heisenberg equation for expectation value of operator product given Heisenberg equation of each operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, operators, quantum-electrodynamics, differential-equations

The problem is following: I have given two equations for creation and annihilation operators:

$\dot{a}(t) = \left(-i\omega -\frac{\Gamma}{2}\right)a(t) \tag{1} $

$\dot{a}^\dagger(t) = \left(i\omega -\frac{\Gamma}{2}\right) a^\dagger(t) \tag{2} $

Now I want to obtain the differential equation of the expectation value of their product:

$\frac{d}{dt}\langle a^\dagger(t) a(t) \rangle \tag{3}$

I know that the result should be:

$\frac{d}{dt}\langle a^\dagger(t) a(t) \rangle = -\Gamma \langle a^\dagger(t) a(t) \rangle \tag{4} $

This might be very easy, but I do not really have a strong background in these things.

I actually managed to get the result in 2 ways:

1. Calculate the solution of each operator which is easy in this case and then multiply their solution and obtain that:

$a^\dagger(t) a(t)=a^\dagger(0) a(0)e^{-\Gamma t} \tag{5}$

The problem with this, I think, is that it is not an expectation value and, secondly, differential equations of each operator might not aways be so easy to calculate.

2. I used the chain rule:

$\frac{d}{dt}a^\dagger(t)a(t)=\dot{a}^\dagger(t) a(t)+a^\dagger(t) \dot{a}(t) \tag{6}$

Now, plugging in the RHS Eqs. (1) and (2), it becomes same as in Eq. (4)

Here, again, the problem is, that it is not the expectation value. How one would treat this problem?

Comment: You're quite close, do you understand what the expectation value is? What's stopping you from taking the "expectation" of the operators on both sides of Equation (5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite close, you just need to take the expectation value of Equation (5) in your question.

In the Heisenberg picture, the operators are assumed to evolve in time, not the states. The expectation value of an operator $O(t)$ in a state $|\Psi\rangle$ is thus: $$\langle O(t) \rangle = \langle \Psi | O(t) | \Psi \rangle.$$

Using this definition in Equation (5), and the fact that $\Gamma$ is just a number, you should easily be able to see that:

$$\langle a^\dagger(t) a(t) \rangle = \langle a^\dagger(0) a(0) \rangle\,\,\, e^{-\Gamma t}.$$

In other words, if we call $F(t) = \langle a^\dagger(t) a(t) \rangle$, then $F(t)$ satisfies the following equation:

$$F(t) = F(0) e^{-\Gamma t},$$ which should make it obvious that $F(t)$ is the solution to the differential equation $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}F(t) = -\Gamma\, F(t),$$ which is what you want to show.

Comment: Thank you for the help! As I understand, expectation value is just a representation (or physical variable, if I might say) of operator in a particular state. For different states there will be different expectation values of the operator. Am I right?

Comment: I'm not completely certain I understand the first part of your question, but to the second: yes, the expectation value will certainly change with the state. However, the equation will continue to hold independent of the state, since you're performing the same operation on either side of the equality. If two operators are equal, then their expectation values in any state will also be equal. Note that the converse need not be true. If two expectation values are equal for a particular state, it doesn't mean that the operators are equal.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks! So if, for example, the solution would not be so easy to find, it would be possible to use 2nd approach in my question by, again, just taking the product as the expectation value?

Comment: Well, it depends: since the state itself is independent of time, you could of course say that $$\langle\Psi | \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} O(t)| \Psi \rangle = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}  \langle O(t) \rangle.$$ However, keep in mind that in general $\langle A(t) B(t)  \rangle \neq \langle B(t) A(t) \rangle$. In this case, both the terms in the sum boil down to having a common factor, but that may not happen in general.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you very much!